# Why is my message not showing for anonymous user?

Tags: forms, ajax, 9, status-messages

In a custom form, I have this Ajax submit:

```
  public function ajaxSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      $messages = Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();
      $messages = [
        '#theme' => 'status_messages',
        '#message_list' => $messages,
      ];
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#messages', ''));
      $response->addCommand(new AppendCommand('.region-highlighted', $messages));
    }
    else {

      some code...

      // Completion message -----------------------------------------------------
      if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
        $str = $this->t('membership request');
        $sMessage = $this->t('Your @str has been registered.<BR>It will be effective after reception of your payment.', ['@str' => $str]);
        Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($sMessage);
        $sMessage = $this->t('A confimation email has been sent.');
        Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($sMessage);
      }
      else {
        switch ($form_state->getStorage()['status']) {
          case 1:
            $sMessage = $this->t('Your wish has been recorded.');
            break;
          case 3:
            $str = $this->t('membership renewal request');
            $sMessage = $this->t('Your @str has been registered.<BR>It will be effective after reception of your payment.', ['@str' => $str]);
            break;
          default:
            $sMessage = $this->t('Renew membership: Unexpected case.');
        }
        Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($sMessage);
      }

      $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand(Url::fromRoute('<front>')
        ->toString()));
    }
    return $response;
  }

}
```

When the code is executed by a logged in user, it works fine: user is redirected to front page and the message (for example 'Your wish has been recorded.') is displayed.
When the user is anonymous, redirection works but no message!
What is wrong with my code?

Update:
Adding `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';` at the beginning of `buildForm()` didn't work. So I tried to add it at the end of `buildForm()` and I realized that I already have `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'association/membership';` for some javascript.
So I updated my library to:

```
LoM:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  css:
    theme:
      css/ahover.css: {}
      css/datatable.css: {}
  js:
    js/LoM.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - shared/shared

LoP:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  css:
    theme:
      css/ahover.css: {}
      css/datatable.css: {}
  js:
    js/LoP.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - shared/shared

membership:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/membership.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal.ajax
```

But it still doesn't work!
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That usually happens if `core/drupal.ajax` has not been attached.

Comment: How do I do that? Adding `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';`at the beginning of `public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`?

Comment: By the way, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I tried differently. See my updated question...

Comment: Is the frontpage cached?

Comment: I don't know (how can I find out?). And how is is relevant?

Comment: You can try this simplest code to test: whether message visible to anonymous user or not :
public function ajaxSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if(\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()){
      $msg = 'logged anonmymous';
    }else{
      $msg = 'not anonmymous';
    }
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($msg);
      $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand(Url::fromRoute('<front>')
        ->toString()));
    return $response;
  }

Comment: It can give you hint issue is with code lines or cache or theme related

Comment: I think I figured it out: I had a `drupal_flush_all_caches()` in my code just before the 'Completion message' part... Once removed, it works as expected. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Yes that makes sense , this is the root cause of status msg not visible to anonymous user

Comment: In this form, I create/update a custom content entity. I used `drupal_flush_all_caches()` to be sure these modifications to the entity would be immediately available. How can I do that without clearing all caches?

Comment: Cache metadata.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Not here, add cache metadata when rendering the entity. I'm voting to close the question because it was solved in a way that doesn't help others. Cache metadata is a different topic.

Comment: OK. I get it. I will answer my question to close this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `drupal_flush_all_caches()` that was the reason of message not showing. Once removed, everything works as expected.